# Why doesn't this user have a bronze tag badge?

Tags: support, badges

[Mat's Mug has a score of 154 on 35 non-wiki answers for vba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug?tab=tags), but he's [not recieved](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23788/mats-mug?tab=badges&sort=name&page=2) a [bronze tag badge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze). Why is that? I thought the requirements were a score of 100 on 20 non-wiki answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order for a tag to qualify for tag badges, it must be applied to at least 100 questions.  So far, [vba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba) has only 69 total questions.

Comment: Keep 'em coming then!